# react-native-camera takes forever to fulfill promise

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I'm using [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) to take pictures in my app. When I call `capture`, the promise takes forever (around ~5 seconds) to fulfill. Sometimes it's quicker (~2 seconds), but sometimes it never gets fulfilled at all as the callback never gets called.

Is this normal during development? Or is there a memory leak or some other sort of performance issue happening?

Comment: please share the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, In development mode, if you are using a bunch of logs in your code then it would take a time to click a pic. I have gone through the react-native camera lib there are lots of issues so, I would prefer to use react-native-image-picker.

Cheers:)